# Checkout GWT project from SVN server in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have already import my gwt project into svn server but the problem is how could I checkout this project as gwt project in eclipse from another machines?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file > new > project > checkout project from svn

[Details here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)

If you have correctly set up eclipse to use gwt, you should simply be able to check out a project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked in the `.project` file of your project you're all set as long as the GWT plugin is installed on the other machine.

The project natures

```
<nature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</nature>
<nature>com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppNature</nature>
```

as well as the builder

```
<buildCommand>
    <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

are defined in it.

If that doesn't work (sometimes it didn't for me) you have to manually activate GWT for the checked out project: `Project > Properites > Google > Web Toolkit > Use Google Web Toolkit`.